# Replace elements in sparse matrix created by Scipy (Python)

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a huge sparse matrix in Scipy and I would like to replace numerous elements inside by a given value (let's say `-1`).

Is there a more efficient way to do it than using:

```
SM[[rows],[columns]]=-1
```

Here is an example:

```
Nr=seg.shape[0] #size ~=50000

Im1=sparse.csr_matrix(np.append(np.array([-1]),np.zeros([1,Nr-1])))
Im1=sparse.csr_matrix(sparse.vstack([Im1,sparse.eye(Nr)]))
Im1[prev[1::]-1,Num[1::]-1]=-1 # this line is very slow

Im2=sparse.vstack([sparse.csr_matrix(np.zeros([1,Nr])),sparse.eye(Nr)])

IM=sparse.hstack([Im1,Im2]) #final result
```

Comment: What do you mean by nomerous? How are they arranged? Do you want to replace an entire row or column?

Comment: By numerous I intend ~ 40 000 elements to replace.

Actually I have to replace one element by row or by column

Comment: Do they have the same values? Or is it everytime only an isolated random entry with random value? Maybe you could supply an example?

Comment: Ok, can you in addition supply - by editing your question - a minimal working example?

Comment: I just added an example

Comment: Look at the various `sparse` matrix types.  For example, `csr` says: `changes to the sparsity structure are expensive (consider LIL or DOK)`.  But even with those many assignments are expensive, since they use standard Python operations (on lists of lists and dictionaries).  I would try to do any assignments in building block arrays, outside of `sparse`.

Comment: Upgrade to Scipy 0.14.0 to get better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played around with your `sparse` arrays.  I'd encourage you to do some timings on smaller sizes, to see how different methods and sparse types behave.  I like to use `timeit` in `Ipython`.

```
Nr=10 # seg.shape[0] #size ~=50000
Im2=sparse.vstack([sparse.csr_matrix(np.zeros([1,Nr])),sparse.eye(Nr)])
```

`Im2` has a zero first row, and offset diagonal on the rest.  So it's simpler, though not much faster, to start with an empty sparse matrix:

```
X = sparse.vstack([sparse.csr_matrix((1,Nr)),sparse.eye(Nr)])
```

Or use `diags` to construct the offset diagonal directly:

```
X = sparse.diags([1],[-1],shape=(Nr+1, Nr))
```

`Im1` is similar, except it has a `-1` in the `(0,0)` slot.  How about stacking 2 diagonal matrices?

```
X = sparse.vstack([sparse.diags([-1],[0],(1,Nr)),sparse.eye(Nr)])
```

Or make the offset diagonal (copy `Im2`?), and modify `[0,0]`.  A `csr` matrix gives an efficiency warning, recommending the use of `lil` format.  It does, though, take some time to convert `tolil()`.

```
X = sparse.diags([1],[-1],shape=(Nr+1, Nr)).tolil()
X[0,0] = -1  # slow warning with csr
```

Let's try your larger insertions:

```
prev = np.arange(Nr-2)  # what are these like?
Num = np.arange(Nr-2)
Im1[prev[1::]-1,Num[1::]-1]=-1
```

With `Nr=10`, and various `Im1` formats:

```
lil - 267 us
csr - 1.44 ms
coo - not supported
todense - 25 us
```

OK, I've picked `prev` and `Num` such that I end up modifying diagonals of `Im1`.  In this case it would be faster to construct those diagonals right from the start.

```
X2=Im1.todia()
print X2.data
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  0.  0.  0.]]
print X2.offsets
[-1  0]
```

You may have to learn how various sparse formats are stored.  `csr` and `csc` are a bit complex, designed for fast linear algebra operations.  `lil`, `dia`, `coo` are simpler to understand.